# Html button with two actions

Tags: javascript, html, button, action, display

I am trying to create a button using html that takes the users input from a status box and displays it on another page. I already implemented the "go to another page" part, but couldn't do the text part. Can anyone help me with this?

```
<div class="button-group pull-right">
        <p class="counter">255</p>
        <a href="/xx/x.php" onClick= class="btn btn-primary">post</a>
     
      </div>
```

Comment: You are describing a `<form>`

Comment: could you add your code so that I can check exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi, you need to study a lot, You could start here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score -2):

You can not do this. When you send user to other page, it's refreshing all of page code. If you need send data to other page, you should work with database. First you need write to DB data and when your second page will open, you must read data from your DB.

Comment: This simply is not accurate

Comment: This is not correct. There are multiple ways to do this.

Comment: How can you do this for example?